# Ubuntu 16.04 After Rebuilding Squid Source Package Getting Error: Failed to start Raise network interfaces

Tags: 16.04, networking, xubuntu, virtualbox-networking

I'm running on a virtual hosted Ubuntu 16.04 server.
It is an IPv4 -> IPv6 setup and I received the IPv6 WAN addresses from my provider.

I configured my /etc/network/interfaces file like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp

iface enp1s0 inet6 static
    address xxxx:bc8:247b:100::/56
    accept_ra 1

iface enp1s0 inet6 static
    address xxxx:bc8:247b:100::/64
    accept_ra 1
```

It seems that the last part causes the error:
"Failed to start Raise network interfaces."
This happened after trying "sudo systemctl restart networking".

```
iface enp1s0 inet6 static
    address xxxx:bc8:247b:100::/64
    accept_ra 1
```

This only happened after I rebuild the squid package via source:
    https://www.metahackers.pro/spoof-http-header-using-squid-proxy

Because before I rebuilt squid the above configuration did work, I even had 100+ extra IPv6es configured and all worked and were pingable from the outside. + I was able to use them as a proxy.
I rebuild squid to enable "--enable-http-violations" and thus be able to create elite proxies. After I rebuilt everything worked, then 8-10 hours later all of a sudden all my IPv6es are not working anymore and I got the error message explained above.

This is my ifconfig:

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:08:a2:0b:49:70
          inet addr:xx.xx.169.13  Bcast:xx.xx.169.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: xxxx:bc8:247b:100::1/56 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::208:a2ff:fe0b:4970/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:29809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2718587 (2.7 MB)  TX bytes:1780201 (1.7 MB)
          Memory:dfe00000-dfe7ffff

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:624 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:624 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:60301 (60.3 KB)  TX bytes:60301 (60.3 KB)
```

Complete error message:

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-01-08 09:48:56 CET; 8s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 2595 ExecStop=/sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment --exclude=lo (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3176 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3170 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --
 Main PID: 3176 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 08 09:48:56 sd-126671 dhclient[3185]: DHCPACK of xx.xx.169.13 from xx.xx.169.1
Jan 08 09:48:56 sd-126671 ifup[3176]: DHCPACK of xx.xx.169.13 from xx.xx.169.1
Jan 08 09:48:56 sd-126671 ifup[3176]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 08 09:48:56 sd-126671 ifup[3176]: bound to xx.xx.169.13 -- renewal in 2147483648 seconds.
Jan 08 09:48:56 sd-126671 ifup[3176]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 08 09:48:56 sd-126671 ifup[3176]: Failed to bring up enp1s0.
Jan 08 09:48:56 sd-126671 systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 08 09:48:56 sd-126671 systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Jan 08 09:48:56 sd-126671 systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 08 09:48:56 sd-126671 systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What can I do to resolve this and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The rebuild of the squid packages is not the source of problem. Squid or the squid package rebuild does not touch the network configuration.

The errer message `RTNETLINK answers: File exists` indicates, that it could be some problem with the default gateway configuration ([1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13895/solving-rtnetlink-answers-file-exists-when-running-ifup) or [2](https://blog.karssen.org/2013/03/28/solving-rtnetlink-answers-file-exists-when-running-ifup/)). Since the `/etc/network/interface` has 3 entries for the `enp1s0`, 2 of them with the `accept_ra` option enabled. There is not much information about that option in the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/interfaces.5.html), but it migth be, that the router advertisements tries to add another default gateway.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it did seem to not be the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

After removing below:

```
iface enp1s0 inet6 static
address xxxx:bc8:247b:100::/56
accept_ra 1
```

The problem got solved.. Don't ask me why, but it seems that subnet 56 and 64 did not like to be together in the interface file.. lol

All my IPv6es are up and working amazingly!